# Ignore changes in git pull

Tags: github, server, gitlab-ci, gitignore, pull

I have a server with my dev version and an own JSON database for the server.
Local, i have the newest integrated features with an own database too (so i can modify & co.)
My goal is that i can develope localy and if it's ready I execute git pull on the server and everything is there, except my local database.
So i added "/databases" to the .gitignore, pushed it and deleted the files in the github repository. Then i made my changes and pushed them to the git, but the /databases folder was there again. So i deleted it and pulled localy which deleted my local database. (Why???? i added it to the git ignore). If i pull it on the server, it would probably delte the real database. What can i do?

My gitignore:

```
/databases
.DS_Store
```

Comment: Try it with `/databases/*. The prerequisite is, of course, that the `.gitignore` file is one structure lower than the databases folder.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I now can push it to the git and there's no database folder - that's good. But if i pull it on the server, it says that the files in ./databases would be overwritten by merge. I added `/databases/*` to the gitignore in the server too.

Comment: Then is the `.gitignore` on remote not the same as the local one. How do you added `/databases/*` on the server?

Comment: it's `/databases/*`
`.DS_Store`

Comment: And "How do change the `.gitignore` on the remote"? With a commit?

Comment: The gitignore is correct everywhere (local, on github and on the server)
(/databases/*)

Comment: I just changed the file.
Anyways, fixed it: 1. Backuped the databases, uploaded my local code to the server and replaced the database, everything works fine now.